# Use stack layout as expo-router slot child route

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-router

I am currently using expo router 2 with expo SDK49.

I would like to add a child route of a slot layout to be rendered as a stack layout - ie whole screen replaced with a back button. I can't seem to make it work and I can't seem to find anything in the docs.

I've produced a minimum example, attached below.

Any help would be appreciated.

Project structure

```
app
├── _layout.tsx
├── index.jsx
├── meow
│   └── test.tsx
└── woof
    ├── _layout.tsx
    └── test.tsx
```

app/_layout.tsx

```
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import { Slot, Link } from 'expo-router'
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native-safe-area-context'

const Layout = () => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
      <Header />
      <Slot />      
    </SafeAreaView>

  )
}

const Header = () => {
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}> 
      <Text> Header </Text>
      <Link href='/meow/test' asChild>
        <Text> Click here to render meow into slot </Text>
      </Link>
    </View>
  )
}

export default Layout
```

app/index.jsx

```
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'

const Page = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Hello world</Text>
    </View>
  )
}

export default Page
```

meow/test.tsx

```
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'expo-router'

const Page = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>I am at meow, in a slot.</Text>
      <Link href='/woof/test'>
        <Text>Going to woof, should be a stack.</Text>
      </Link>
    </View>
  )
}

export default Page
```

woof/_layout.tsx

```
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import { Stack } from 'expo-router'

const Layout = () => {
  return (
    <Stack />
  )
}

export default Layout
```

woof/test.tsx

```
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'

const Page = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>This is supposed to be a stack child!</Text>
    </View>
  )
}

export default Page
```

Here are the screenshots of each screen:

[Initial screen on app open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98nh1.png)

[Clicked on meow, rendered into slot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F248z.png)

[From meow to woof with a stack layout but rendered into slot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17ZHL.png)

I've also tried having a meow/_layout.tsx with a Stack layout which doesn't work either.

Is it even possible to do what I am trying to do with Slot? If not, are there any workarounds?

Thanks in advance,